# C programme return 0 while the pointer point to value 3

Tags: c, pointers

I thought at the end of the programme, il will print 3 but in fact it is 0.

Can anyone explain how it is happening ?

Here is the code :

```
int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};
char *p;
p = arr;
p = (char*)((int*)(p)); // two conversion, means nothing, omit
printf("%d, ", *p);     // point to 2, 
p = (int*)(p+1);  // point to 3 ?
printf("%d", *p);
return 0;
```

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler let you assign a `int*` to a `char*`.

Comment: You should get compilation errors for lines 3 and 6. A cast is required.

Comment: What you intended on line 6 was `p = (char *)( ((int *)p) + 1 );`, then it will point to the `3`.

Comment: @RSahu for GCC compiler, it gives warning but enable by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are treating an array of integers like an array of chars. The line that is marked as "means nothing" actually means a lot.

When you increment `char* p` by one, you shift your pointer one byte, but in order to point to the `arr[1]` you need to increment it `sizeof(int)` bytes. Declare `p` as `int* p`, then `p+1` will do what you need.

Comment: I see. you mean char* p is followed by 3 bytes of 0, that's where comes the final value. thank you, very clear.

Comment: The line marked "means nothing" actually does nothing. It converts the pointer to `int*` and then back to `char*`. Since there is actually an `int` at the target location, this is well-defined and the resulting pointer must equal `p`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: Yep, you are right, for some reason I read it as it explicitly casted `arr`, not `p` to `char*`. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Since `p` is of type char, `p+1` points to one byte past the start of the first integer. So when you read one byte by dereferencing p, you are reading a position in the integer array that contains a zero byte.

Answer (score 2):

If you increment a pointer, it is incremented by its type's size. Here `p` is character pointer, and If you increment `p` it points to next character. As character is of 1 byte, `p+1` points to next byte to that pointed by `p`. If `p` had been an integer pointer, `p+1` would point to next integer i,e 3 in your code.

Answer (score 1):

#### What's going on?

The following lines print `char` **content** (here `*p`) in `int` **format**.

```
char *p;
printf("%d, ", *p);
```

It prints `2` because the (current) machine is little-endian (e.g. x86). If this code is run on a big-endian machine, it would print `0`. [For endian-ness, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness ]

Exercise: If the array initialization is changed to the following, what is the expected print output?

```
int arr[3] = {0x1a2b3c4d, 3, 4};
```

#### Pointer increments

Let's say we have

```
char * pc = 0xA0;
int  * pi = 0xB0;

pc += 1;    // pc = ?
pi += 1:    // pi = ?
```

What are the new values of `pc` and `pi`?

Since `pc` is a pointer to `char`, the `+ 1` increments `pc` by `sizeof(char)`, which is 1.

However, since `pi` is a pointer to `int`, the `+ 1` increments `pi` by `sizeof(int)`. In 32 bit system, `sizeof(int)` is typically 4, whereas in a 64 bit system, `sizeof(int)` is typically 8.

```
pc += 1;    // pc = 0xA1
pi += 1:    // pi = perhaps 0xB4 or 0xB8
```

#### Word of Caution

It is okay to experiment for knowledge and curiosity sake, but in real code, accessing the bytes of an `int` by casting it to `char *` is not a good idea, it leads to all sorts of endian-portability issues.